# Java Media Framework

Tags: java

What JMF library files need to be imported into a java project that requires this framework in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just download the standard pack and import the files within. Depending on the media format that you want to work on, you may also want to install any third-party plugins/additional codecs, but it seems that these are very limited.

From Wikipedia:

> Many JMF developers have complained that the JMF implementation supplied in up-to-date JRE's supports relatively few up-to-date codecs and formats. Its all-Java version, for example, cannot play MPEG-2, MPEG-4, Windows Media, RealMedia, most QuickTime movies, Flash content newer than Flash 2, and needs a plug-in to play the ubiquitous MP3 format. While the performance packs offer the ability to use the native platform's media library, they're only offered for Linux, Solaris and Windows. In particular, MS Windows-based JMF developers new to JMF often expect support for some newer formats on all platforms when such formats are only, in fact, supported on MS Windows.

#### Relevant links

- [JMF 2.1.1 Download page at java.sun.com](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/download.html) (with installation instructions)

  - [Versions and performance packs](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/setup.html)
  - [Tutorials and Code Camps](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/index.jsp)
- [Wikipedia/Java Media Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework) (with list of alternatives)